# How to sum the series $\sum_{i=1}^n \theta^{a(i)}$, where $a(i)=i(i-1)/2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

This is my very first post, and I was wondering how we can sum the following series

$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \theta^{a(i)},$$

where $a(i)=i(i-1)/2$. I don't know if this can help, but $a(i+1) = a(i)+i$. More properties of this sequence can be found in http://oeis.org/A000217

Thanks!!

Comment: Where does this come up? What is $\theta$? Do you need an exact formula (very unlikely, IMHO) or an approximation; or is a $O(\cdot)$-type bound enough?

Comment: To be sure, this is not from any textbook but something that I happen to come up with while doing some research. The $\theta$ is some constant taken to be $0<\theta<1$, but this shouldn't really matter. I can obviously upper bound it as $S_n \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \theta^i$. However I would really like to have an exact expression.

Comment: A better bound (but still quite loose) is given by the sum of the geometric series up to $n (n - 1) / 2$.

Comment: Yes, obviously!! My last resort would be to use the Euler-Maclaurin formula, but isn't there a simple way of doing it?

Comment: Euler-Maclaurin requires you to know it's $\gamma$, and that isn't much easier...